# Python selenium automatic

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am working on a Python Selenium tool that accesses a URL on a page, clicks on ads, waits for 30 seconds, and then returns to the page to retrieve a "pcode". When performed manually in Selenium by moving the mouse and clicking on ads, this code is displayed, but when the script runs these actions automatically, the code does not appear. Does anyone have a solution?
[link-video](https://streamable.com/g6oq4f)The first 45 seconds of the script running show no code, and in the last 40 seconds, I clicked manually.

```
def click_ad_and_trigger_ajax(driver, timeout=10):
    try:
        # find iframe
        iframes = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")
        ad_iframe = None
        for iframe in iframes:
            src = iframe.get_attribute("src")
            if src.startswith("https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net") or src.endswith("/html/container.html"):
                ad_iframe = iframe
                break

        if ad_iframe is None:
            print("iframe not found")
            return
        
        # Mouse over
        driver.switch_to.frame(ad_iframe)
        ad_element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
        actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(ad_element)
        actions.perform()
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.click(ad_element)
        actions.perform()
        
        
        # wait 30s
        time.sleep(30)

        
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

My code: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WOuhDACSDzCa7e8V8SXhR09Gtih3gPja?usp=sharing
My inputURL : https://crm.indoglobenews.co.id/?job=ba40d67c7529&worker=500e282a